# Installing OSs from a hard drive

Tags: installation, operating-systems

I work in QA and we test on 32 and 64-bit versions of Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8. We are always getting in new hardware or having to rebuild systems. We have old outdated discs and have recently made updated slipstreamed images of the OS's. The problem is with the security concerns of our NDAs, getting them on disk has been an issue, especially if we want to keep them updated from time to time.

I am looking for a way to plug in a SATA HDD and boot the installations from there to a seperate HDD for a new system build or clean install on a current build. If possible, I would like to basically have it pop up a boot menu that has options of Install OSa, Install OSb....

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called [WinNTSetup](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/149612-winntsetup-v23/). It runs in one instance of Windows and allows you to install another one.

Now you can take that HDD and drop a portable instance of Windows there (for example MiniXP, remember that you need separate license for that one), then add contents of Windows installation disks and you have it.

If you want a menu from which you could choose which Windows to install, then [NT 6.x Fast Installer](http://reboot.pro/topic/10126-nt-6x-fast-installer-install-win7-directly-to-usb-external-drive/) may better suit your needs, but as far as I remember it won't work with XP.

Comment: thank you so much. i have been using hbcd and didnt even notice these were already in there. btw, i am having trouble with the drivers for minixp for sata on some of the older systems. i am used to installers, and not sure which files and where to place. any help appreciated.

Comment: In my opinion the only reason why one should use MiniXP is its portability. For any other application it's better to strip full version of XP with [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/). Minimal mostly functional ISO is about 200 MB and it installs and runs very fast. SATA drivers are usually loaded in the installer from a floppy (otherwise installer won't see drives), but you can also integrate them with nLite so that's probably your best option.